# Why method returns -1?

Tags: java, return-value

I read code from one book and have this method:

```
public int getScore(String name) {
  try {
     //some code here
     return score;
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return -1;
  }
}
```

Why this method in catch returns -1? Why not 5? Is that some convention?

Comment: I didn't program the method, how can I know?

Comment: This is all well and good until someone uses it for Golf. Exceptions are superior to 'magic number' return values every time.

Comment: @Marcelo, it's ok if you didn't progaram method, but you still could answer my question. I asked if this is some convention or not?

Comment: @glowcoder, you want to say that there is no need for return value in catch code?

Comment: @Иван Бишевац I'm saying this is a poor choice of catch. You're essentially saying "Hey, something went wrong. I don't care what, I'm just going to give this default value." You should **only catch Exceptions that you can actually do something about**. In this case, you can't do anything other than tell the calling method that something happened. I will elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are the one choosing what you want to return as you are the only one who knows how you want to handle that returned value. I personally use `-1` too when I want to detect an error, and I know a lot of people doing the same.

Answer (score 11):

-1 is a standard error code when the caller expects a positive int

but really in that case a wrapped `RuntimeException` or a more specific one would have been much better

Comment: I guess it's a beginner book, I know I wouldn't have liked a RuntimeException thrown in my face when I started :)

Comment: @talnicolas, it's book [link](http://www.amazon.com/JavaSpaces-Principles-Patterns-Practice-Freeman/dp/0201309556/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1313533710&sr=8-1)

Comment: @talnicolas you wouldn't have liked to, but it would have been better for you if you had. Judging by your answer, which advocates magic numbers over exceptions, you are in need of a better book. And that book is hardly for beginners. It's for Javaspaces, a framework for distributed server state and algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the author uses this code to make sure *something* gets returned, and the caller of `getScore` can check to see if a `score` was correctly called.

In code:

```
int theScore = getScore("My Name");

if(theScore == -1) {
    // Oh no, there was an error!
}
```

We can use the check for -1 to make sure that the code knows when `getScore` fails.

Answer (score 3):

> Why method returns -1?

Because it is very poorly designed to do so on *any* exception. The method would have been better designed by declaring it to throw the exception(s) of interest and specifically by *not* catching all the `RuntimeExceptions` as well.

Answer (score 2):

The reason they picked -1 instead of 5 is because -1 is not a feasible score to return from the getScore method.  Therefore, when you call the function, you can easily check if it was -1 returned or not.

If it was a function that could realistically return -1 for a successful run, -1 would be a poor choice of a flag indicator.  A more appropriate choice, then, might be -9999 or something ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is we don't know what the exceptions are. Catching every exception is a very poor decision. Those exceptions were thrown for a reason so you would know exactly what went wrong and can deal with it appropriately.

Bad:

```
public int getScore(String name) {
  try {
     int score = scores.getScoreForName(name);
     return score;
  } catch (Exception e) { // catches everything
     e.printStackTrace();
     return -1;
  }
}
```

Marginally better...

```
public int getScore(String name) {
    try {
     int score = scores.getScoreForName(name);
     return score;
  } catch(NameNotFoundException) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return -2; // now we know what happened, not just a general error
  } catch (Exception e) { // catches everything
    e.printStackTrace();
    return -1; // generally error
  }
}
```

Much better:

```
/**
 * Get the score for a given name. Will throw a runtime exception if the 
 * name doesn't exist.
 * @param name The name to get the score for
 * @return the score for the name
 * @throws NameNotFoundException if the name doesn't exist in the database.
 */
public int getScore(String name) {
    return scores.getScoreForName(name);
}
```